# Simple string sending through System.Net in C#

Tags: c#, client, server, port, tcpclient

Firstly, I am working on C# Windows Forms.

Second, I want to send simple strings(texts) from one application to another through the System.Net namespace.
There are just two applications, the master which manages all data, and the worker which sends data to the master app when a textbox gets hit with enter.
Also, the master sends some data at initializing both apps.

Now, I got this code for server:

```
int Port = 9090;
IPAddress serverAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(serverAddress, Port);
listener.Start();

TcpClient myTCP_Client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

NetworkStream myStream = myTCP_Client.GetStream();
byte[] data = new byte[myTCP_Client.ReceiveBufferSize];

int bytesRead = myStream.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(myTCP_Client.ReceiveBufferSize));
//string receivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead));
```

And I got this for client:

```
int myPort = 9090;
TcpClient myClient = new TcpClient();
myClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", myPort);
NetworkStream myStream2 = myClient.GetStream();
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Something here");

//myStream2.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

So, I have an idea of what means each line of code in the two blocks above. But I do not know where to put them in each of my forms.

For example, I need to know which piece of code I should put in a Connect Button for both Server and Client. I also need to know where I should put the code needed to receive the entering data.

If someone thinks that there is a better solution to this, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.  - CCB

Comment: You may find that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001434/async-tcp-server-message-framing-advice/16001812#16001812) answer heads off some disappointment and/or confusion when using the Power and Grace of TCP.

Comment: Why don't you use WCF web service? which can be hosted using WebServiceHost