# Socket.BeginReceive merging TCP packets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcp

Is there a setting I can use to prevent merging multiple TCP packets into a single buffer inside `Socket.BeginReceive` callback?

Your knee-jerk reaction will be that there is nothing I can do to prevent TCP from splitting/merging the data, but **this is not what I asking**; I can clearly see individual packets being received in Wireshark, and my only concern is latency, i.e. to process the segment as soon as it arrives. This doesn't mean I don't know how to process split/merged segment, but it means I want to avoid the delay.

My code looks like this:

```
void WaitForData(ISocketInfo soc)
{
    if (socket != null && socket.Connected)
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 
            SocketFlags.None, OnPacketReceived, socket);
}

void OnPacketReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    try
    {
        var socket = (ISocketInfo)asyn.AsyncState;

        numberOfBytesReceived = socket.EndReceive(asyn);
        if (numberOfBytesReceived > 0)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesReceived);
            OnNewDataReceived();
        }

        WaitForData(socketInfo);
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Log.Warn("Socket error while receiving packet", ex);
        Close();
    }
}
```

When I examine these packets in WireShark, I can see individual TCP packets being received every 50ms, each of them (say) 100 bytes. But sometimes in my app there is a delay of 100ms, and the `OnPacketReceived` methods gets 200 bytes.

Since WireShark confirms that this is not a OS/networking issue, what could be the problem here? The `OnPacketReceived` just fires on a background thread so it doesn't block the method, and the program doesn't really consume much CPU.

**(Update)**

It seems like I didn't convey my question clearly enough. My problem is not how to parse the data if it gets split across segments. My protocol is well defined (i.e. START_COOKIE, LENGTH, DATA, CRC), and I enqueue the data into a byte FIFO as soon as I receive it (the `_queue.Enqueue` call inside the snippet above), so I can easily parse it asynchronously.

The question is, if I am seeing packet no. 1 (100 bytes) at +50ms in Wireshark, and packet no. 2 (100 bytes) at +100ms in Wireshark, and my application is not blocking the `OnPacketReceived` method and consuming no CPU, how come does .NET, every once in a while, invoke `OnPacketReceived` at +100ms and merge two packets into one?

Comment: _what could be the problem here?_ There is no problem here.  TCP is an endless **stream**, and the behavior you're describing is standard **and expected**.  It's up to you program in a way to deal with partial "messages" coming in, and multiple "messages" being received at once.  Either with byte lengh prefixing, message delimiters, or a combination of those things.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001434/async-tcp-server-message-framing-advice/16001812#16001812) answer provides a little more information.

Comment: @Idle_Mind: I think you misunderstood the question. I am queueing all data into a FIFO buffer anyway, and I can easily parse it, the format is well defined. But the question is: if Wireshark is showing **two actual individual TCP packets** being received by the network card, why does .NET create an additional delay and merge two packets into a single buffer? My concern is latency, not parsing. And second, TCP is not "an endless stream", it's a protocol for transmitting a (potentially) endless stream of data in segments.

Comment: It is most likely not even .NET which merges the incoming data. It could already happen in the OS. If two packets which contain data for a TCP connection are received in a short time period their content will both be put into the TCP receive buffer, and the application will simply read from this buffer. It can't see whether this was one or two packets. If it happens once in a while maybe your app is busy with something (garbage collection?) and doesn't fetch the first packet while the second is received.

Comment: The TCP stack will buffer data and handle [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control). It can buffer data at will and may combine "packets" or, via the sliding window mechanism, stop the flow of data in the middle of a "packet", i.e. if your messages are 50 bytes and the receive window is only 28 bytes then you may get a fraction of a message. All of this is happening below .NET. ("Packet" is a bit of a misnomer. As segments are forwarded from node to node they may be split or combined depending on the links, buffers, ... .)

Comment: @HABO: Wireshark displays all TCP segments as they are received/transmitted by the network adapter. It even shows Ethernet and IP headers, then the TCP header, and then it analyzes the data protocol (it's a standard protocol). The transmitting microcontroller assembles two individual TCP packets. Wireshark shows two individual packets. And my .NET handler is invoked once (sometimes) with the data merged.

Comment: @HABO: So I am certain two packets were sent, and Wireshark in Windows is clearly showing **two packets** being received by the adapter at **exactly the expected timestamps**. And then I am getting only a single event being fired, which reports double the size of data. If both the device and the Windows machine are alone on the same network switch (and latency is very important here), I would like to see if anyone knows at which level does this happen (OS or .NET). It's certainly **not** related to TCP flow control. This happens every once in  a while, just to mention again.

Comment: As long as there is receive buffer space available for the socket the system will offer a window size >0, regardless of whether your application is consuming data. When your application receives data the number of bytes should be the smaller of the application's buffer size and the number of bytes of data accumulated in the TCP stack's receive buffer. The stack is, from your perspective, part of the O/S. You could try setting [Socket.ReceiveBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivebuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx) to the message size, but that would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

You may receive less or more, there is no guarantee you will receive exactly what was sent.

From MSDN:

> There is no guarantee that the data you send will appear on the network immediately. To increase network efficiency, the underlying system may delay transmission until a significant amount of outgoing data is collected. A successful completion of the BeginSend method means that the underlying system has had room to buffer your data for a network send.

[Here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) is a good article to explain this and how you can fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I asked. The data protocol is well defined with a start cookie/length/crc, so I am enqeueing the data into a FIFO and I parsing it sequentially regardless of how it's being split/merged during transmission. My question was: if Wireshark is showing two actual individual TCP packets being received by the network card with 50ms delay, how com does .NET (every once in a while) skip delivering the first packet, create an additional delay, and then merge two packets into a single buffer, while the app is not doing practically anything to prevent instant delivery?

Answer (score 0):

[TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is a continuous stream of data by definition (it is its main feature, to make it seems as if there were no packets at all, unlike UDP). Thus, it's up to your software to define the message format. You could:

- Mark the beginning of each message with the length of it (http does that).
- Add separation mark to the end of the message (/n). To let the receiver know when to start and stop reading a single message, mark both the beginning and the ending of the message (use special symbols that cannot be typed).

To sum up, you have to care of splitting the stream into messages. Or use HTTP, WebSockets or other message format implementations on top of TCP.