# socket communication works on the same machine but not between different machines

Tags: c#

I wrote a client/server application to send a file. It works if the server and client are on the same machine, but when I put the server on another machine, I get errors when the server reads the socket.

This is the code of the server:

```
class conexion
{
    int sizeofonpacket = 9999;
    string filsc="";
    string titre = "";
    bool sendfilcomand = false;
    int conteur1 = 0;
    int conteur2 = 0;
    BinaryWriter sf;
    TcpListener listiner;
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream netStream;

    public conexion(IPAddress ip, int port)
    {
        listiner = new TcpListener(ip, port);
        listiner.Start();
        client = listiner.AcceptTcpClient();
        netStream = client.GetStream();
        Console.Write("client is present \r\n ");
    }

    public void read()
    {
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            string returndata;
            int size = 0;
            string c = "";
            byte[] bs = new byte[4];
            byte[] b = new byte[1];

            try
            {
                //read the comand of client "s" for string or "b" for binary file if it is "s" it read the string that client write
                //if it is "b" we read the string "dfgjsdgfjdsgfjhdsgfj" it is not important 
                Console.Write("ready \r\n ");
                netStream.Read(b, 0, 1);

                c = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n comand  :" + c);
                b = new byte[4];
                netStream.Read(b, 0, 4);
                returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
                size = Int32.Parse(returndata);
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n size de packet int =" + size);
                b = new byte[size];
                netStream.Read(b, 0, size);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n conexion echoue");
                listiner.Stop();
            }

            switch (c)
            {
                case "b":
                    if (sendfilcomand == false) //if sendfilcomand is false we read first the title
                    {
                        sendfilcomand = true;

                        break;
                    }
                    sendfilcomand = false;
                    filsc = titre;
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\nle titr est:" + titre);

                    titre = "";
                    sf = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(filsc, FileMode.Create));

                    conteur2 = 0;
                    conteur1 = size;
                    crebfile(b);
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n creat file for " + conteur2 + " to " + conteur1);
                    b = new byte[sizeofonpacket];
                    while (size != 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            netStream.Read(bs, 0, 4);

                            returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bs);
                            size = Int32.Parse(returndata);

                            conteur1 = size;
                            Console.WriteLine("sizee a get" + size);

                            if (size == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("yout est termine");
                                sf.Close();
                                conteur1 = 0;
                                conteur2 = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (size != sizeofonpacket)
                            {
                                b = new byte[size];
                            }
                            netStream.Read(b, 0, size);
                        }
                        catch 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\r\n imposible to read ");
                        }

                        crebfile(b);
                        b.Initialize();
                    }

                    sf.Close();
                    conteur1 = 0;
                    conteur2 = 0;
                    break;

                case "s":
                    returndata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + returndata);

                    if (sendfilcomand)
                    {
                        titre = returndata;
                        Console.WriteLine("titre a get" + titre);

                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n rien comand");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public string quadripl(string s)
    {
        while (s.Length < 4)
        {
            s = "0" + s;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public void crebfile(byte[] byts)
    {
        try
        {
            sf.Write(byts, 0, conteur1);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("imposible de crer le fichier");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
class conexion
{
    string filsr;
    int sizeofonpacket = 9999;
    bool sendfilcomand = false;
    bool getfilcomand = false;
    int bali;
    int fali;
    Stream file;
    TcpListener listiner;
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream netStream;

    public conexion(string ip, int port)
    {
        listiner = null;
        Console.Write("star client ");
        client = new TcpClient(ip, 3568);
        netStream = client.GetStream();
    }

    public void send()
    {
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            //enter the comand "s" or "b"
            string c = "";
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n ecrir comand:");
            c = Console.ReadLine();

            string s = "";
            if (c == "s")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n entrer string:");
                s = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            string size = "";
            Byte[] sendBytes = null;
            //try
            {
                switch (c)
                {
                    case "b":
                        Console.WriteLine("\r\n comand binary file");
                        netStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c), 0, 1);
                        if (sendfilcomand == false) //we will first send the patsh of file after we will send data of file
                        {
                            sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("dfgjsdgfjdsgfjhdsgfj"); //this is not important
                            size = quadripl(sendBytes.Length.ToString());
                            netStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(size), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(size).Length);
                            netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                            sendfilcomand = true;
                            s = getitr();
                            c = "s";
                            goto case "s";
                        }
                        sendfilcomand = false; //now we will send data
                        filsr = actitr(); //the title is save in "C:/Users/Ce-Pc/Desktop/titreactuel.txt"
                        file = new FileStream(filsr, FileMode.Open);
                        fali = (int)file.Length;
                        bali = 0;
                        byte[] bs = new byte[4];
                        Console.WriteLine("\r\n star sending ");
                        do
                        {

                            sendBytes = filebtobyte(filsr); //read part of file to send
                            Console.WriteLine("\r\n terminer " + bali + " " + " " + fali);
                            size = quadripl(sendBytes.Length.ToString()); //just for add the zero
                            Console.WriteLine("\r\n le size de fichier binair est " + size);
                            netStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(size), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(size).Length);

                            netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);

                        } while (bali != -1); //when we come to last part of the file (filebtobyte give -1 to bali)
                        bali = 0;
                        size = quadripl("0");
                        Console.WriteLine("\r\n terminer fiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiin ");
                        netStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(size), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(size).Length);
                        netStream.Read(bs, 0, 4);
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        Console.WriteLine("\r\n comand string");
                        netStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c), 0, 1);
                        size = quadripl(s.Length.ToString());
                        sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(size);
                        Console.WriteLine("\r\n size=" + size);
                        netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                        sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
                        netStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);

                        if (sendfilcomand)
                        {
                            c = "b";
                            goto case "b";
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\r\n rien comand");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n imposible de transfer");
            }
        }
        Console.Write("client est deconect \r\n ");
    }

 //////////////////the functions//////////////////////////////////

    public byte[] filebtobyte(string s)
    {
        byte[] byts = null;
        try
        {
            if (fali - bali < sizeofonpacket)
            {
                byts = new byte[fali - bali];
                file.Read(byts, 0, fali - bali);
                file.Close();
                bali = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                byts = new byte[sizeofonpacket];
                file.Read(byts, 0, sizeofonpacket);
                bali += sizeofonpacket;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("imposible de trouver le fichier");
        }
        return byts;
    }
    public string quadripl(string s)
    {
        while (s.Length < 4)
        { s = "0" + s; }
        return s;
    }

    public string getitr()
    {
        StreamReader titrfil = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Ce-Pc/Desktop/titre.txt");
        string sss = "";
        try
        {
            sss = titrfil.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n le chemin " + sss);
            titrfil.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n imposible");
        }
        return sss;
    }
    public string actitr()
    {
        StreamReader titrfil = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Ce-Pc/Desktop/titreactuel.txt");
        string sss = "";
        try
        {
            sss = titrfil.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n le chemin " + sss);
            titrfil.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n imposible");
        }
        return sss;
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16001812/92546) answer may shed some light. Note that `NetworkStream.Read` returns the number of bytes read. You don't appear to care and simply assume that you'll get what you want. When you run the client and server on separate machines there is a real network in between which will tend to fragment large transmissions, something that might not be apparent running on a single system that just shuffles buffers around.

Comment: thank you for the answer
but i think that the tcp protocol guaranteed send the information

Comment: When you use `netStream.Read(b, 0, 4);` without getting the return value, how do you know that four bytes were read? This becomes more problematic with `netStream.Read(b, 0, size);`. When the size exceeds the typical Ethernet frame size of about 1500 bytes there will be fragmentation. Try limiting the size of a packet to something smaller, e.g. 1200 bytes. Then get a copy of [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and see what is really moving between machines.

Comment: i try to use a size equal 1400 but is not success
he send a false data in some step of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your firewall between the two machines?

Try a telnet test from a command prompt on the client PC to connect to the port on the server PC:

```
telnet <server ip> 3568
```

If this fails, there's an issue at the network level (probably firewall related).

Also, double check you are using the same port for client and server (you don't show the server port in the code above)

Comment: no i dont thinck that it is the firewall
because send string is worck
and the smalle fille can send but if ther is a big fille
it not send all the data of file

Answer (score 0):

Your code is cut and I don't know what you put in, so I can't predict the answer accurately. Here are 4 possible answers:

(**Please read the whole answers**)

- Firewall might be blocking the connection (as Ryan mentioned). You can disable it in the control panel
- Make sure you typed in the correct server address to start the TCP Listener (and never the local default ip: **127.0.0.1**). To find the correct ip address, open cmd, type, 'ipconfig', in the section called 'Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:', copy the **Ipv4 Address**. For the client you must type in that Ipv4 address generated from the **other machine**. The Ipv4 is highlighted in yellow.[image]
- If both solutions don't work, then I have to ask you if they are in the same Wi-fi. If not, then it wouldn't work (of-course) else if you are running it from live server in the internet and not in the router.
- If it's not an error in client/server then it must be with your code to send/receive. Sending byte[] through the internet doesn't not guarantee that the other side will receive it as whole (it's split into small packets), your code must know when to start receiving and when to stop receiving. You can add a small header at the beginning of your data that will tell how long the file is and how many more bytes left to read.

  ---

## Update:

You want to receive the data as whole and not by small pieces. So I created some functions that will help you send and receive data easier:

```
static void sendMessage(string c_1)
    {
        byte[] command = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(c_1);
        byte[] commandLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command.Length.ToString());
        List<byte> commandLengthInByteArray = commandLength.ToList();
        while (true)
        {
            if (commandLengthInByteArray.ToArray().Length < 50)
            {
                commandLengthInByteArray.Add(Convert.ToByte('x'));
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        byte[] parsedCommandLength = commandLengthInByteArray.ToArray();
        sck.Send(parsedCommandLength);
        sck.Send(command);
    }
    static void sendMessage_ftp(byte[] data)
    {
        byte[] commandLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data.Length.ToString());
        List<byte> commandLengthInByteArray = commandLength.ToList();
        while (true)
        {
            if (commandLengthInByteArray.ToArray().Length < 50)
            {
                commandLengthInByteArray.Add(Convert.ToByte('x'));
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        byte[] parsedCommandLength = commandLengthInByteArray.ToArray();
        sck.Send(parsedCommandLength);
        sck.Send(data);
    }

static byte[] getResponse(Socket sck)
    {
        byte[] CommandLengthInByteArray = ReadBytes(50, sck);
        List<byte> commandLengthInByteArrayList = new List<byte>();
        foreach (byte b in CommandLengthInByteArray)
        {
            if (b.ToString() != "120")
            {
                commandLengthInByteArrayList.Add(b);
            }
        }
        Int32 fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(commandLengthInByteArrayList.ToArray()));
        byte[] data = ReadBytes(fileSize, sck);
        return data;
    }
    static byte[] ReadBytes(Int32 size, Socket sck)
    {
        //The size of the amount of bytes you want to recieve, eg 1024
        var bytes = new byte[size];
        Int32 total = 0;
        do
        {
            var read = sck.Receive(bytes, total, size - Convert.ToInt32(total), SocketFlags.None);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                //If it gets here and you received 0 bytes it means that the Socket has Disconnected gracefully (without throwing exception) so you will need to handle that here
            }
            total += read;
            //If you have sent 1024 bytes and Receive only 512 then it wil continue to recieve in the correct index thus when total is equal to 1024 you will have recieved all the bytes
        } while (total != size);
        return bytes;
    }
```

---

## How to Use it:

- To send text: `sendMessage("SomeTextHere");`
- To send file (>1 GB) `sendMessage_ftp(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\StackExchange\Desktop\Image.png"));`
- To receive file or text as whole (not my pieces):

  > > `byte[] messageOrFile = getResponse(sck);`
  > >
  > > ---

## But...

You'll have to get rid of using `TcpClient` and instead use `System.Net.Sockets`

**You must:**

- Replace: `TcpClient client;` with `Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);`
- Replace: `client = listiner.AcceptTcpClient();` with `client = listiner.AcceptSocket();`

Comment: Setting the IP on the server side is also important -- it can be 0.0.0.0 or its own IP address (the same one entered into the client program), it should not be set to 127.0.0.1 or the client computer's address.

Comment: This is not a firewall or ip error the client and server are connected
and my code know when to start receiving and when to stop receiving because even the big fille (50 mb) can send if i'm in the same machine
the client can send the string and small fille
the problem is when i send a big data of file in this case the data is not send corectly

Comment: @MadaraItachi I see your problem. Take a look at my solution once more!

Comment: ok thank you very much for your answer
i will try this solution if it work even i don't know what is wrong in my code
thank you for a second time for take your time and write all this

Comment: @MadaraItachi Thank you! I would like to see if the result. I'll be waiting for the result

Comment: yes brother now it work thank you very much
and sorry for i'm late because i have lot of exam and i don't have a time for testing
but now i finished and i test your function and it work so thank you