# Send/Read data to/from a socket SQL Server/Python

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, sockets

Using SQL 2016 & Python 3.7

I currently have two python programs:

- A server that receives input from a socket and returns output
- A client that sends a prompt to the socket, reads the response and then outputs.

I then have a script in SQL Server that uses xp_cmdshell to run the client and read the results.  I'd like to be able to remove the client from the process by using SQL Server to directly access the socket.  Unfortunately since you can access SQL Server as a socket, my searches are receiving a high level of noise and not giving me the results I need.

If I upgrade to SQL2017 I can use the internal python option to run the client locally, however upgrading will not be an option for some of our cients and I need a one size fits all solution.

**Example Server:** SimpleSocket.py:

```
import socket
from _thread import *

HEADER_LENGTH = 10


def threaded(local_client_socket):
    command_header = local_client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
    command_length = int(command_header.decode("utf-8"))
    command = local_client_socket.recv(command_length).decode("utf-8")

    if not command:
        print('Connection closed by client')

    print("Received from client:", command)

    reply = f"You sent me '{command}' This is my reply.".encode("utf-8")
    reply_header = str(len(reply)).zfill(HEADER_LENGTH).encode("utf-8")

    local_client_socket.send(reply_header + reply)

    local_client_socket.close()


def open_sockets():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9878))
    print("Socket bound to port", 9878)

    s.listen(16)
    print("Socket is listening")
    print("-" * 80)

    while True:
        client_socket, address = s.accept()
        print('Connected to :', address[0], ':', address[1])
        start_new_thread(threaded, (client_socket,))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    open_sockets()
```

**Example Client:** SimpleClient.py

```
import socket
import sys

HEADER_LENGTH = 10

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 9878))

command = "Text I'm sending to server".encode("utf-8")
command_header = str(len(command)).zfill(HEADER_LENGTH).encode("utf-8")

client_socket.send(command_header + command)

reply_header = client_socket.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

if not len(reply_header):
    print("Done")
    sys.exit()

reply_length = int(reply_header.decode("utf-8"))
reply = client_socket.recv(reply_length).decode(("utf-8"))
print("Reply from server:", reply)

client_socket.close()
```

**Example SQL Call:**

```
DECLARE @Python_Location NVARCHAR(255) = N'c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Search\python.exe'
,       @Python_Script   NVARCHAR(255) = N'c:\PythonScripts\Search\SimpleClient.py'
,       @Command         NVARCHAR(255)

SET @Command = N'"' + @Python_Location + N' ' + @Python_Script + '"'

PRINT @Command;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'cmdshell';

    EXEC xp_cmdshell @stmt = @Command;

REVERT;
```

I have used OLE Automation in the past to pull data from a webservice, so was wondering if that may be an option.  It's not really an area I know well and my searches haven't turned up anything relevant.

I'd be interested in knowing any options available to me, and all offerings gratefully received.  Even if you don't have a full answer, any help may send me in a good direction, or help me structure my search queries to be more relevant.  I may even be able to adjust the python code to output the result set to a different format if there's an efficient option.

Many thanks.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16001812/92546) answer provides a clue re: sockets handling "messages".

Comment: Hi HABO.  Good suggestion, but unfortunately not something thats going to make a difference here.  I have the socket server configured and working fine.  I also have a socket client configured and working fine.  What I'd be look for though is how to read data from a socket directly in SQL.  Many thanks for the suggestion though - that would have been handy for a previous issue I'd already solved.

Comment: The code I'm using actually generates a data set, and returns that instead.  That's why there' s separate header length and message information being passed around.  The examples I included only transmit very basic data to illustrate the concept.

Comment: It would be possible to do this in SQL CLR procedures, but not something I'd recommend for various reasons - security and stability among them. Why can't your client be an external process, like a Windows Service (e.g.: python inside srvany), that inserts the received data into SQL table(s) to be acted upon?

Comment: Hi AlwaysLearning.  The code actually did that originally. (writing to table not CLR)  I've found opening a connection from the script, doing a table insert, then reading that data from the table is far slower than running via the intermediary call.  An up vote for the solution as it may well help someone else.  It shows we were both thinking along the same lines.